# Set sound as ringtone without WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Tags: android

As far I know, to set a sound as ringtone it should be inserted in MediaStore. And for writing in MediaStore, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is required. But... is there a way to set a sound (a MP3 file in external storage, for example) as ringtone without requiring WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: Any solution so far?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Android's `RingtoneManager`. There is a method called [setActualDefaultRingtoneUri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(android.content.Context, int, android.net.Uri)):

> **public static void setActualDefaultRingtoneUri (Context context, int
>   type, Uri ringtoneUri)**
>
> Sets the Uri of the default sound for a given sound type.
>
> Parameters
>
> - context: a context used for querying.
> - type: the type whose default sound should be set. One of `TYPE_RINGTONE`, `TYPE_NOTIFICATION`, or `TYPE_ALARM`
> - ringtoneUri: a Uri pointing to the default sound to set.

You can get the Uri of a file by using `File.toURI()`.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but when I go to sound settings -> notification sound, instead of seeing my sound selected, I see "unknown"and no sound is selected.

Comment: @SergioViudes, same problem here, I see the unknown named sound, and even the sound file doesn't exist in the ringtone list, what have you done for this , please share it.